# Neo4j JSON APOC load - skip nulls

Tags: json, neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to load some `JSON` from a `REST API` (using Neo4j 3.0.4 & APOC apoc-3.0.4.1-all) that has null values in it.  This is throwing up this error:

> "Cannot merge node using null property value"

The nulls can be spread across multiple keys and it varies which keys have null values.  Hence I'd prefer to avoid specifying which individual keys to handle nulls for if possible.

I found the `apoc.map.clean(map,[keys],[values])` procedure but not much info on how to use it.  Is this the best procedure to use this for every key or is there an simpler way?

Thanks!

Comment: It would be better if you show an example of "JSON" data and an example of a query, where you can get this error.

Comment: Here is an example json document:                                                            doc: {
key1: ,
key2: value x,
key3: value y
}                                                                                                                               As you see key 1 is blank, the others are not. Therefore the below wouldn't work: MERGE (label:Label {Property1: key1, Property2: key2, Property3: key3})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks stdob - I managed to find another post you had written which helped me to understand solution. I need to substitute the first property for one that was never null.

MERGE (label:Label{key2: json.key2}) ON CREATE
SET label.key3 = json.key3, label.key1 = json.key1